# Android Optional GPS Permissions

Tags: android, permissions, gps, location

I made the location permissions optional by having :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
```

But when I down the app from the Google Play store it still shows Location permission in the dialog:
[image]

What am I missing to make the permission optional ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing permissions with device features. The device feature tag tells the store which devices can download a certain app because they have the correct hardware. Imagine your app has no sense in a device without GPS, they shouldn't download it. That is the meaning of the optional on device features.

In Android all the permissions you declare in the manifest will be presented in the Play Store. This is because the word Optional has no sense at all for the android permissions, at least until Android M.

When you declare a permission for your app you are just saying that your app can access to a resource. It doesn't matter if you are doing it so or the user will use it, but in the moment you have the permission declared, it will be presented to the user.

In Android M (the next major release) some permissions can be revoked by the user, so the apps have to check if they have enough permissions to execute some actions, but still, they will be shown on this Play store dialog.

Comment: Ok, I was aware of that info but the way you're explaining it makes sense. Question is, do I remove the permission declarations and just leave the features ?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing in your app. If your app accesses the GPS, you can't remove the permission since it won't allow you to request updates (I mean location updates). And of course, if you remove the permission, the feature is not needed anymore, you are not using it. Are you taking how it works?

Comment: To clarify I dont want the app to be filtered by play store and not show up on devices without GPS. Location permissions are not critical for the app, most of the app will still work as expected.

Comment: In this case, your configuration is ok. The feature tags are not required, but having them there with required:false doesn't hurt you ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's correct though, because adding / removing feature tags has an effect on number of filtered devices.

Comment: From doc: The element offers a required attribute that lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the feature but can function without it.

Comment: And another good reason to have it, from doc again: However, other services (such as Google Play) or applications may check your application's <uses-feature> declarations as part of handling or interacting with your application. For this reason, it's very important that you declare all of the features (from the list below) that your application uses.